# Sort search results by sum of top N answer votes rather than question votes

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, search, sorting

In a recent podcast, Joel complained about how people weren't upvoting questions often, so even well-answered questions didn't rise to the top of searches sometimes.

Would it help to implement a sort that sorts search results by the sum of the votes of the top N answers? This would help excavate the useful answers to dumb/badly worded/boring questions.

Comment: Good answers and good questions can be completely independent. One does not have to infer the other.

Answer (score 2):

This is a factor in [the hotness calculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions).

Comment: So maybe we could address the problem by allowing search results to be ordered by hotness.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there should be a **total thread votes** number, in which everything is added. Then you would be able to sort threads by their accumulated votes in the question + N answers.